# Rerun previous command immediately in zsh instead of creating it

Tags: zsh, command-history

I know I can re-run a previous command using `!!`, but doing this in zshell only grabs the command and puts in on the new line, which requires me to press enter again to execute it.

For example:

```
~ echo test
test
~ !!
~ echo test
```

*Bash* does not seem to do that and it executes the command immediately. Can I achieve such behavior in zsh?

Comment: I set a simple example. Usually the use of this is to run `sudo !!`

Comment: under `zsh -f` the `!!` runs the previous command for me. have you altered the defaults anywhere?

Comment: Not that I know of, I installed oh-my-zsh and some plugins. The answer suggesting `unsetopt HIST_VERIFY` helped though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `unsetopt HIST_VERIFY`.  Add that to your `.zshrc` is you want the change to be persistent.  See `man zshoptions`.

Comment: Note that oh-my-zsh turns this back on, so set this _after_ importing that (if you do so) in your RC file.